# Run exe from current directory in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to run 2 *.exe files from whatever directory the batch file is located in. Commands:

```
@echo off
:A
cls
Echo programs
start %1myprogram.exe
start %1myprogram1.exe
exit
```

This works perfect when I open my batch file simply by double clicking it, but it doesn't work when I run the batch file as administrator. I need to do this as the two exe's have to have administrator privileges. I suspect this error occurs because it runs the batch file as if it were in the SYSTEM32 folder. Is this correct?

Thanks for your help!
Erik

Comment: you are right. Go to the batch file's directory with `cd %~dp0` before starting the EXEs.

Comment: @Stephan that's add because when I do this on my PC it works perfectly, but when I try it on another laptop it says it can't find the two exe's

Comment: are you sure, that those exe's are where you think they are? (Also `%1` is quite useless, if you start your batch with a doubleclick.)

Comment: @Stephan they are right beneath the batch file in the script folder I made

Comment: As @Stephan mentions, try: `start "%~dp0\myprogram.exe"`

Comment: Although `"%~dp0\myprogram.exe"` results to the same as `"%~dp0myprogram.exe"`, use `start "" "%~dp0myprogram.exe"`. It's because `%~dp0` expands to a drive letter and path of the batch script itself but this includes a trailing `\`. And in `START "title" ...` syntax that `"title"`, a text for the CMD window title bar, is required, obligatory parameter (might be an empty string, still required none less)

Answer (score 5):

Although the answer is in the comments, it should be as an actual answer so that this question is removed from the "unanswered" list.

```
@echo off
:A
cls
echo programs
cd %~dp0
start %1myprogram.exe
start %1myprogram1.exe
exit
```