# How to run a .bat (that runs an .exe that is in the same directory) as administrator from a pendrive?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm able to run a .bat (that runs an .exe that is in the same directory) as administrator: I right-click in the bat file and select "Run as administrator".

To be able to do that, I used the following answer: [Run exe from current directory in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386658/run-exe-from-current-directory-in-batch)

Here's the code:

`@echo off
:A
cls
echo This will start the program.
pause
cd %~dp0
start %1myprogram.exe
exit`

However, this will only work if the .bat file and the program are in the system drive.

Because if they are, for instance, in a pendrive, and I right-click and select "Run as Administrator", I get the error:

"*Windows cannot find 'myprogram.exe'. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again.*"

Why this happens and how can I fix it?
I thought that by using *cd %~dp0* it would always point to the folder in which the bat .file resides.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**
Change *cd %~dp0* to *cd /d %~dp0*

**Explanation**
When you run something with administrator privileges, the working directory changes to:
'C:\Windows\System32'
Although %~dp0 still points to the drive and the directory containing the batch file, cd %~dp0 does not work, because it only changes the directory, but stays on the same drive.
Using the /d parameter, you can tell the cd-command to change the drive, too.

Comment: sorry, but the `cd` command *is*  able to change drives. Use the `/d` parameter: `cd /d %~dp0`

Comment: I did not know this. I'll edit my answer, so pushd is not longer misused.

Comment: @Stephan - thanks for the info on `/D`; it was new to me, too.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to tell cd to also change drives:

```
cd /d %~dp0
```

Answer (score 0):

If the current drive is C: (e.g., the prompt says `C:\>`), and you do `CD D:\FOO`, the current directory on drive D: is set to \FOO, but you will still be "on" drive C:. Try the following:

```
@echo off
:A
cls
echo This will start the program.
pause
cd %~dp0
%~d0
start %1myprogram.exe
exit
```

(also, why `%1myprogram.exe` instead of just `myprogram.exe`, or even just `myprogram`? If you're right-clicking on the batch file to run it, there isn't going to be a `%1`.)

Comment: Jeff, you're are right, the %1 isn't necessary. I've removed it.